# How to Wrap a file with Tags in Bash

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have an `xml` file named `test.xml`, without a root tag like this:

```
<cat></cat>
<name></name>
<id></id>
<cat></cat>
<name></name>
<id></id>
```

How can I wrap this file with a root tag to make the output look like this:

```
<root>
  <cat></cat>
  <name></name>
  <id></id>
  <cat></cat>
  <name></name>
  <id></id>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with redirection:

```
(echo "<root>"; cat test.xml; echo "</root>") > wrapped-test.xml
```

And with indention:

```
(echo "<root>"; sed 's/^/  /' test.xml; echo "</root>") > wrapped-test.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

In line number one insert before it (`i\`) the opening tag, and in last line (`$`) append after it (`a\`) the closing tag (I didn't care about the formatting with spaces):

**EDIT**: I forgot to say that `GNU` version of `sed` is needed.

Content of `script.sed`:

```
1 i\
<root>
$ a\
</root>
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

With following output:

```
<root>
<cat></cat>
<name></name>
<id></id>
<cat></cat>
<name></name>
<id></id>
</root>
```

Comment: sed -i '1s/^/<root> /' test.xml  Solved the Problem

Comment: or even just `sed -e '1i<root>' -e '$a</root>' -e 's/^/    /'`